# How would you build a curseword filter for an 8 character alphanumeric string?

Tags: python, search, filter

I want to create 8-character alphanumeric combinations and filter for cursewords. The idea is that each of the eight characters can be up to but not necessarily all 36 characters. If I for instance have a selection of n characters at each position and I would like to add a new character at x position, how could I efficiently filter out cursewords in major languages as well as any instance of a repeating character. Examples:

-7ARPASS8 - Not good

-7ARPASX8 - Fine!

-7AAAAAAA - Not good

I have developed a python script that creates combinations based on the available letters at each position and then filters out combinations that contain a curseword (contained in a long list of curseword and curseword alternatives with numbers) with the new letter in question. It takes forever though once I introduce more than ~10 characters at each of the 8 positions.

Feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: So, could you post the code and ask a specific question. Code review is elsewhere.

Comment: Make sure you don't make a [clbuttic mistake](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-).